# Somar uma coluna com dados no formato Varchar2

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Quero fazer o somatório da coluna Valor que é do tipo Varchar2, sei que para usar o SUM() tenho que usar também o GROUP BY, só que não estou conseguindo fazer o somatório. Não sei quais campos tenho que colocar no GROUP BY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.sales_office AS kam, z.customer,g.sales_order,
d.nfnum, d.vlr_liq_nf AS valor FROM TPL_GUARDA g 
LEFT JOIN TPL_COLETAS c     ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN humo h            ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
LEFT JOIN DANFE_DELIVERY dd ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
LEFT JOIN danfe d           ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
LEFT JOIN zzcustmon z       ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order 
where c.dt_exp is null and d.nfnum is not null and z.delivery is not null 
GROUP BY
```

Comment: O que você quer como resultado? Quer o somatório do Valor de cada cliente? Quer o somatório do Valor de cada escritório?

Comment: Quero somar  todos os valores da coluna VALOR(d.vlr_liq.nf). Fiz igual o amigo comentou logo a baixo, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, no oracle, a tratação de vírgula é diferente, virgula não quer dizer virgula. Estava dando o erro Invalid Number, por causa da virgula, o oracle não conseguia fazer a conversão. Então usei o replace para substituir a virgula por um ponto, e usei um outro select para que não precise usar o group by. Segue o código funcionando:

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(valor,',','.')) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT z.sales_office AS 
kam, z.customer,g.sales_order,
d.nfnum, d.vlr_liq_nf AS valor FROM TPL_GUARDA g 
LEFT JOIN TPL_COLETAS c     ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN humo h            ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
LEFT JOIN DANFE_DELIVERY dd ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
LEFT JOIN danfe d           ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
LEFT JOIN zzcustmon z       ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order 
where c.dt_exp is null and d.nfnum is not null and z.delivery is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendo em conta que precisa somar uma coluna que é do tipo `VARCHAR`, precisa converter a coluna para isso.

Depois, no `GROUP BY` precisa colocar todas as outras colunas que não estão a ser somadas.

No seu caso seria algo deste género:

```
SELECT      z.sales_office                          AS kam
        ,   z.customer
        ,   g.sales_order
        ,   d.nfnum
        ,   SUM(TO_NUMBER(d.vlr_liq_nf, '9999.99')) AS valor 
FROM        TPL_GUARDA      g 
LEFT JOIN   TPL_COLETAS     c   ON g.SALES_ORDER   = c.SALES_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN   humo            h   ON h.HANDLING_UNIT = g.handling_unit 
LEFT JOIN   DANFE_DELIVERY  dd  ON dd.delivery     = h.delivery 
LEFT JOIN   danfe           d   ON d.nfnum         = dd.nfnum 
LEFT JOIN   zzcustmon       z   ON z.sales_order   = g.sales_order 
WHERE       c.dt_exp    IS NULL 
        AND d.nfnum     IS NOT NULL 
        AND z.delivery  IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY    z.sales_office
        ,   z.customer
        ,   g.sales_order
        ,   d.nfnum
```

Dê uma olhada ao método `TO_NUMBER` para perceber qual o formato que deve utilizar, tendo em conta o formato que tem na coluna `d.vlr_liq_nf`.

> https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php

Comment: Não deu certo, apareceu o erro ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Isso é porque o seu valor em VARCHAR não pode ser convertido para um número. Vou editar a resposta para poder testar de outra forma.

Comment: Muito obrigado, fico no aguardo

Comment: Feito! Experimente com o formato correto no método `TO_NUMBER` e veja se resulta.

Comment: Ainda continua exibindo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Qual o formato do valor que tem na coluna `d.vlr_liq_nf`?

Comment: Ele é do tipo VARCHAR2. Esse é um valor que tem na coluna: 44986,54

Comment: Muito obrigado @JoaoMartins, ajudou bastante.

Comment: De nada, sempre às ordens! Dê um UP na resposta caso tenha ajudado. Obrigado.